# How to find first day of year using 3 years ago from today’s date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, getdate

I am looking to write how to find the first day of the year (January 1st) from 3 years ago using today’s date. I know I can utilize `Getdate()` in this and minus 3 years, but need help on the rest.

```
WHERE datefield >= …
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You get the year with the `YEAR` function. Use `DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, day)` to construct the date.

```
WHERE datefield >= datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 3, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one option:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, DATEADD(yy, -3, GETDATE())), 0);
```

### Demo

Comment: This should do the job. `DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0)`. One `DATEADD()` less

Comment: @Squirrel Well it looks like my answer just hit a bump!

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2022 you can use [`DATETRUNC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for this need

```
SELECT DATETRUNC(Year, getdate())
```

returns the first day of the current year

so

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, -3, DATETRUNC(Year, getdate()))
```

returns 3 years before that